# High Ping On Only My PC

Tags: windows-10

I've had this PC which I've built myself (WINDOWS 10) for a little over 4 months now and have had no issues. Recently after traveling to a friends house with the PC (Who's internet is generally faster than mine) when I returned home my PC had unbelievably high ping. I have run speedtest.net multiple times with results like 489ms, 678ms, 807ms, which are all very inconsistent. When I try to play a game like CSGO my ping is through the roof at over a thousand. However, when I turn off the PC the Internet is completely normal. But as soon as the PC is turned back on, the Internet goes back to being awful. It's like something on the PC is sucking literally all the life out of my internet. If anyone has a solution to this problem please help, thank you!

Comment: Is it quick to ping the router? Are you using any QoS ?

Answer (score -1):

**Will be hard work of investigation... :/**

Try install Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/#download).
With them you can see all traffic in network of your computer and destination url.

[image: Wireshark]

Or

Try this more simple: TCPView
This you can see applications with yours active connections.

[image: TCPView]

Comment: Thank you! I downloaded TCPView and looked at the results. On Windows 10 the MS application OneDrive was literally destroying the internet. I was able to end the process and everything is working perfectly fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good, NolaN. Happy for you. If i help you, help me please... upvote may answer e select as the accepted answer. Any downvote and i'm sad lololo... /// Good for you. OneDrive e DropBox is hard for home network when downloading...